# Compiler misunderstanding

Tags: c++, oop, assembly

I have the following code:

```
IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* ori_iat;
ori_iat += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA)

generates the asm:

MOV EAX, ORI_IAT;
ADD EAX, 10h;
MOV ORI_IAT; EAX
```

Which is not what i wanted since the sizeof of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA should be 8,
now i try this:

```
IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* ori_iat;
DWORD addr = (DWORD)ori_iat;
addr += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
ori_iat = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA)addr;

generates the asm:

MOV ADDR, ORI_IAT;
ADD ADDR, 4;
MOV ORI_IAT, ADDR;
```

Again wrong, now lets try this:

```
IMAGE_THUNK_DATA* ori_iat;
ori_iat += (DWORD)sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA);

generates the asm:

MOV EAX, ORI_IAT
MOV ECX, 10h
LEA EAX, [EAX+ECX*4]
```

Much worst, i dont know how to tell the compiler i just want to add 8 to the current pointer and its really annoying.

**UPDATE:** Also looking at the IMAGE_THUNK_DATA it has 4 DWORDS which is size 0x10h but according to what i am seeing on DUMP on Ollydbg regarding the IMAGE_THUNK_DATA structure its like this:

```
C5 87 87 00 | 00 00 00 00 
DB 87 87 00 | 00 00 00 00 
F7 87 87 00 | 00 00 00 00 
0E 88 87 00 | 00 00 00 00
```

That leads me to think the size of the struct is actually size 8.

**SOLVED:** Thanks for the ++ operator. I am not used to working with pointers, also the IMAGE_THUNK_DATA structure its actually size 4. each IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR points to the next IMAGE_THUNK_DATA, so me bad :)

Comment: Have you considered frame alignment optimizations? Try `-O0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think what you wanted is

```
 ori_iat++
```

because in C/C++

```
       ptr + i
```

is equivalent to

```
       &(ptr[i])
```

Comment: Thanks that pretty much does it, i had the wrong length also of the struct, its size 4 :)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns bytes. Adding 1 to a pointer increases it by size of data type.

```
ori_iat += sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
```

According to you same as

```
ori_iat += 8
```

So, this increases `ori_iat` by `8 * sizeof(*ori_iat)`, which should be 64, not 16 shown in assembly (0x10).

So, `sizeof(IMAGE_THUNK_DATA)` must be square root of 16, which is 4.

And indeed, next snippet of assembler shows that size is actually 4 and not 8 (because you are not adding to pointer, but to a normal integer variable, it will just add the number directly).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i had the wrong size for IMAGE_THUNK_DATA its size 4 and each IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR points to the next record, but there is still a gap of 4 bytes between IMAGE_THUNK_DATA dont know why. probably for padding to 8 bytes...

Comment: @ffenix Fixed the answer, first version was wrong (size of pointer has nothing to do with this).

Comment: Why ollydbg shows something else than 4, I don't know. What is normally understood by padding is included in the `sizeof` of struct, because when used in array, `sizeof` must be separation between array elements. It may be due to alignment to even 8 bytes, when you have a single struct variable, or due to heap block size granularity if it is allocated in heap, or something like that.